# dynamic binding of list of data to list of adaptive card in c#

Tags: c#, json, botframework

I have list of data class file which i want to bind dynamically to adaptive card using c# in bot framework v4
I have tried below :

```
mycsfile.cs

private asynch Task < DialogTurnResult > GetDynamicAdaptiveCard(WaterfallstepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
  //This is my json file where  am having all the data
  string json = File.ReadAllText("path of json file where I have list of data");
  JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
  JArray a = (JArray) o["Info"];
  //converting json data to list of class
  IList < InfoListClass > list = a.ToObject < IList < InfoListClass >> ();
  //This is my json file where  am having adaptive card
  string json1 = File.ReadAllText("path of json file where I have adaptive card");
  JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(json1);
  JArray a1 = (JArray) o1["body"];
  foreach(var item in InfoListClass) {
   ((JObject) body[0])["text"] = item.name;
  }
  Attachment attachment = new Attachment() {
   ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
    Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json.ToString()),
  };
  return await stepContext.PrompAsynch(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions() {
    Prompt = new Activity {
      Type = ActivityTypes.Message,
       Attachments = new List < Attachment > {
        attachment
       },
       AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carausel
     },
     RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please"), cancellationToken);
  }
```

//My adaptive card

```
{
    "type":"AdaptiveCard",
    "body":[
    {
    "type":"TextBlock",
    "size":"Medium",
    "weight":"Bolder"
    "text":"ABC"//This property I am trying to change with my class property in c#
    },
    {
    "type":"ColumnSet",
    "columns":[
    {
    "type":"Column",
    "items":[
    {
    "type":"Image",
    "style":"Person",
    "url":"boy picture path"// This one also I wanted to chnge with a other picture from c# by class property
    "size":"small"
    }
    ],
    "witdh":"auto"
    },
    {
    "type":"Column",
    "weight":"Bolder",
    "text":"Dr"//Thsi will also change from c#,
    "wrap":true
    }
    ]
    ]
    }
```

output: I should get multiple cards because I am having multiple data in my class file, but I am getting only one card with the last list value.
Please can someone tell me how can i get multiple adaptive cards with different values?please can someone help me.
Thank in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at the handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your C# code has a lot of problems that would prevent it from compiling. Where is `body` declared? I suspect you changed a lot of things when you wrote this question so that we're not looking at your actual code, which means we won't be able to help you until you fix that. Try creating a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and test it to make sure it works before pasting it here. Have you seen the Adaptive Card documentation that explains how to do templating? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/templating/